# Is XCB ready for production use? Should I use Xlib instead?

Tags: linux, unix, x11, window-managers, xcb

If one needs low level access to X11 events, windowing and input without using GTK, QT et al., should one use Xlib or [XCB](http://xcb.freedesktop.org/)? What are the pros and cons of each?

Comment: qt5.5.0 use XCB rather than xlib. So I assume xcb is ready for production use.

Comment: Use XCB if you want high performance... and a reasonable dose of pain due to lack of documentation (I _love_ XCB, btw!). Also, a good source for information on XCB seems to be the X protocol itself, since XCB is a fairly thin layer, as far as I can tell

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use both of them. XCB is simpler to use, has a better response to a multithread environment but lacks documentation, while Xlib is a more dated/complex tool, better documented and fully implemented.

I'm currently studying the XCB API and the hardest thing to do is to find docs and good API references..

In the end: if you aim to faster development, you should use Xlib, otherwise XCB is meant to be the future (but it's still far from being such).

Comment: _...the hardest thing to do is to find docs and good API references..._ Very true. Some of the official tutorials are riddled with errors and won't even compile. [Example](http://xcb.freedesktop.org/tutorial/events/)

Comment: 2 years later and I still have a hard time with xcb...

Answer (score 7):

What helps when learning XCB is to look at X11 specification, for example here https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/xproto/x11protocol.pdf

Most XCB calls map directly to X11 requests. The same is true for extensions.